What prevents JavaScript primitives from being mutated?
In C, after declaring and initializing a primitive, we're able to access the memory address where the primitive is stored and directly modify its value. However in JavaScript it is said that primitive values are immutable. Once a string, for example, is created, it is not possible to modify it.
My question is what is preventing us from simply accessing the memory location where the value is stored and directly mutating the value? Is it just convention?
I read elsewhere that when variables are assigned primitive values in JavaScript, the variable points to a pre-determined memory location that represents the primitive value being assigned, rather than an arbitrary location in memory that holds the value specified. For example if I write:
let a = 3;
let b = 3;

Both a and b should point to the same memory address that represents the value 3. Therefore, it wouldn't make sense to say the memory address that JS interprets as the value 3 now holds the value 4. But I'm not sure I understand this notion. How can there ever be enough memory locations to represent all possible primitives out there? Surely I'm misunderstanding something.

Both a and b should point to the same memory address that represents the value 3. — what makes you think that? And why do you think that "all possible primitives" must be representable?

And the answer to the question about accessing the memory location of a value is that you cannot get that information from JavaScript.

"what is preventing us from simply accessing the memory location" — The lack of direct memory location access possibilities.

"How can there ever be enough memory locations to represent all possible primitives out there" — It's not pre-allocating memory for all possible primitive values. And if you do try to create all possible numbers in memory at runtime, you will run out of memory eventually, yes.

@Pointy Thanks for the response. The second part is probably my misunderstanding, but the first part I read from multiple places. Is this not the case?

where did you read that there is a pre-determined memory location that represents the primitive value being assigned - either you misunderstood what you read, or what you read was written by someone who thinks browsers have an infinite amount of memory available to them to pre-determine every possible primitive, of which there are an infinite number

Mutable strings can make sense, but JS just has just chosen to regard them immutable. The question then goes to numbers, but then confusing assignment with mutation. Those are two different mechanisms.

When you're learning JavaScript, the best thing to do is to simply trust the runtime to work properly. These questions are interesting, but they don't do you any good; you have to learn to exploit the facilities of the language and become fluent in converting ideas for software into actual JavaScript. Once you are good at it, then this becomes a little more interesting, but it will remain the case that you can't really do anything about how the JavaScript runtime manages these things.


Both a and b should point to the same memory address that represents the value 3

That's not true. Both a and b point to memory addresses that hold the value 3. Whether or not this is the same address is entirely up to the JavaScript runtime.

How can there ever be enough memory locations to represent all possible primitives out there?

The memory for "all primitive values" isn't pre-allocated. JavaScript allocates memory as it's required. And indeed, it may run out. Consider the following:
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < SOME_HUGE_VALUE; ++i) {
   arr.push(i);
}

Nothing in this example can be garbage-collected, so JavaScript is forced to keep adding values to arr. With a sufficiently large size, this will indeed crash.
